# setTimeout only runs once when i use it inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

im trying to bubble sort some information (by asking users which they prefer instead of compare)
when i use settimeout in callback function it only runs once at the first level of for loop.
(s changes by clicking on images
this is the main function we pass it an array as argument

```
function bubble_Sort(a)
{
    var swapp;
    var n = a.length-1;
    var x=a;
    do {
        swapp = false;



        for (var i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
            s=0;
            limage.setAttribute('src','images/'+x[i]+'.jpg');
            rimage.setAttribute('src','images/'+x[i+1]+'.jpg');
            console.log('images changed');
            check(i,function(){
                if (s==0)
                {
                   var temp = x[i];
                   x[i] = x[i+1];
                   x[i+1] = temp;
                   swapp = true;
                }

            });
        }


        n--;
    } while (swapp);
 return x; 
}
```

and here is check function (callback to wait for user to click on one of images)

```
var check=function(p,callback){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log('this is Timeout');},3000);
    callback();
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: The only code inside your `setInterval` function is a console.log. Not sure why you'd expect it to do anything else

Comment: setTimeout . i dont want it to repeat by itself. i need it to run in every level of the "for loop "

Comment: sorry it was a mistake. just testing something.

Comment: You're callback code will run immediately when you call check

Comment: i need my bubble sort function to wait and give the user time to click and choose one of images

Comment: Then you have a misunderstanding of how this works. You need to look at creating a click handler for your image(s). You won't need to user setTimeout.

Comment: how can i pause the function till user click on something?and how can i get the users action?

Comment: https://codepen.io/lee-taylor/pen/XWrNXWr

Comment: Please add example input and expected output to your question 

Comment: @MohamedAbuGalala an array (teachers id's) as input and an array sorted by user choices as output

Comment: `this is Timeout` will be logged to the console `n` times after 3 seconds (but the callback is called immediately)- check the console output carefully, is there a number to the right of `this is Timeout` which happens to be the same as `n`?

Comment: yes there is a number. exactly i want to know how can i prevent it from running immediately. i need my function to pause till user click on one of images @JaromandaX

Comment: promises make it easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a set-timeout function to implement such functionality, your code has to wait for a click (asynchronous) event to continue it's computation. can get what you want with the help of [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).
here's a simple working sample, the code is mostly self descriptive, hope it helps!

```
// a generator function
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield
function* bubbleSort(items) {
  var length = items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < (length - i - 1); j++) {
      firstImageIndex = j;
      secondImageIndex = j + 1;
      updateUI(); //magic happens here
      shouldBeSwapped = yield i; // wait for user to select a picture (no set timeout here)
      if (shouldBeSwapped) {
        let tmp = items[j];
        items[j] = items[j + 1];
        items[j + 1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  updateUI(); // final update
}
```

[Codepen Link Here !](https://codepen.io/saied_za/pen/bGbBgYr)

Comment: thanks it worked.
Although i changed my algorithm to merge sort but generation function really helped me.